# @PreUpdate never called on respository.save()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a spring-boot 3 app with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class SomeJson {

  public static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  public static final TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> MAP_REF = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};

  // some fields

  public String jsonData;

  @Transient
  public HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  
  @Transient
  private int initialHashCode = 0;

  /**
   * Converts JSON-Data to {@link HashMap}.
   */
  @PostLoad
  public void onLoad() {
    try {
      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(jsonData))
        data.putAll( MAPPER.readValue(jsonData, MAP_REF) );
    } catch (JacksonException ignore) {}
    initialHashCode = data.hashCode();
  }

  /**
   * Converts {@link HashMap} to JSON-String if dirty.
   */
  @PreUpdate
  public void onSave() {
    System.out.println("**** " + initialHashCode + " == " + data.hashCode() );
    if( initialHashCode == data.hashCode() ) return;
    try {
      jsonData = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(data);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {}
  }
  
}
```

and the corresponding repo:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeJsonRepo extends JpaRepository<SomeJson, Long> {}
```

The `@PostLoad` works just fine, but the code

```
SomeJson sj = someJsonRepo.findById(42);
sj.data.put("lastSuccessfulExport", System.currentTimeMillis());
// sj.onSave(); (1)
someJsonRepo.save(er);
log.info( "Authentication failed" );
```

does NOT trigger the `@PreUpdate` method.

If I uncomment the line `(1)`, I see that the `onSave()` is executed twice:

```
**** -888829936 == 1673013342
2024-02-19T11:44:27.913+01:00  INFO 18408 --- [nio-8050-exec-1] some.Service : Authentication failed
**** -888829936 == 1673013342
```

Does JPA/Hibernate have troubles determining whether the instance is dirty and "forgetting" to fire the `@PreUpdate`?

Comment: `data` is `@Transient` so doesn't mark anything dirty so will not update anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum how to extend the dirtyness-check to include a `@Transient` field?

Comment: You don't else it will also be persisted. Why aren't you just mapping the `data` field to the `jsonData` column and use a proper custom type to convert from/to the map. THen you don't need all those `@PostLoad` and `@PreUpdate` mess. Or even better maybe use [this](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils) which already provides a `JsonType`.

Comment: did it before in another project, and it's not worth it. JSON custom type is not represented in java as a map, so marshaling must be done by hand

Comment: If you can do this manually you can do it in a type, without the callback mess.

Comment: alright, the `@Type(JsonType.class)` was a solution for the JSON column (got improved since I last used it). Although I still want to know if a `@Transient` property can participate in dirtyness-check

Comment: No it cannot unless you want to rewrite the JPA engine and do not adhere to the standard anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [entity listener](https://safe.menlosecurity.com/https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html)

@PreUpdate callback method is there you can customize as you wish